# Rails - Creating a Delete Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the following for a delete link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", photo_path(@photo.id), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method=>:delete %>
```

Problem is, if I click CANCEL - it still deletes!!! wooops... Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have to write photo_path(@photo.id), just pass @photo, that's enough.

```
<%= link_to "Delete", @photo, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

If the link doesn't work, that means that your page doesn't correctly load the JavaScript adaptator for your JavaScript framework. For example, if you use use jQuery, check this :

http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Comment: Strange, I upgraded my rails.js and it did the trick, must have been an old bug. Thanks